# Connecting to SMB/CIFS share not working in Thunar on Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, mount, samba, xfce, cifs

I set up a system with the XFCE-spin of Fedora 25.

The thing that is not working for me is connecting to samba (CIFS) shares using the default file manager Thunar. I click on explore network in the sidebar and it automatically finds the samba server I want to connect to. But when I try to connect to it by double-clicking on the entry, I get an error message telling me that the specified location is not supported.

However, if I use Terminal and run `mount -t cifs ... //server/share /mnt` there, I can successfully mount the share and use Thunar to explore `/mnt`.

Why is the usual way via Thunar not working and what can I do to fix that?

Comment: likely needs Thunar invoked with sudo for the mounting part, which is failing without the escalation even if only for the mount and dropped.